# How to prevent this pthread synchronization memory stomping?

Tags: c, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization, pthreads

The following program, in which I use critical sections to protect a writer/readers pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define NAME_SIZE 6
#define NUM_THREADS 4
static char name[NAME_SIZE];
pthread_mutex_t mt;
pthread_cond_t read_phase;

void* name_joey(void *arg);
void* name_jimmy(void *arg);
void* name_leah(void *arg);
void* print_name(void *arg);


int main(void)
{
    pthread_t joey;
    pthread_t jimmy;
    pthread_t leah;
    pthread_t printer;

    pthread_create(&joey, NULL, name_joey, NULL);
    pthread_create(&jimmy, NULL, name_jimmy, NULL);
    pthread_create(&leah, NULL, name_leah, NULL);
    pthread_create(&printer, NULL, print_name, NULL);

    pthread_join(joey, NULL);
    pthread_join(jimmy, NULL);
    pthread_join(leah, NULL);
    pthread_join(printer, NULL);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void* name_joey(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
        memset(name, 0, NAME_SIZE);
        strcpy(name, "Joey\0");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
    }
    return 0;
}
void* name_jimmy(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
        memset(name, 0, NAME_SIZE);
        strcpy(name, "Jimmy\0");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
    }
    return 0;
}
void* name_leah(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
        memset(name, 0, NAME_SIZE);
        strcpy(name, "Leah\0");
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
    }
    return 0;
}

void* print_name(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mt);
        printf("%s\n", name);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt);
        sleep(1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Produces variations on this output:

```
Loey
Leah
Leah
Jimmy
Jimm
Joey
eah
Jimm
Jimmy
Loey
Leah
Loey
Jimmy
imm
Loey
Loeh
Jeey
Limm
Jimm
Jimmy
Leah
Leah
Jimmy
Jimmy
Jimm
Jeah
Loey
Jimmy
Jimmy
Jeah
```

This is not the desired effect. I've provided critical sections to each write/read area of the code, in addition to zeroing out the memory entirely before each write. What could be causing the memory to be partially malformed like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mutex `mt` is use **un**initialised. So the calls to `pthread_mutex_lock()` and `pthread_mutex_unlock()` may not work as expected. This would become obvious if the code checked the latter function's return values, like so:

```
  if (0 != pthread_mutex_lock(&mt))
  {
    /* Handle and log error here. */
  }
```

Handling and logging the error might be done as follows:

```
  if (0 != (errno = pthread_mutex_lock(&mt)))  /* Needs errno.h. */
  {
    perror("pthread_mutex_lock() failed");  /* Requires errno to be set. */
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);  /* Needs stdlib.h. */
  }
```

To initialise a mutex in the simplest case do:

```
pthread_mutex_t mt = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
```

Alternatively do:

```
  if (0 != pthread_mutex_init(&mt, NULL))
  {
    /* Handle and log error here. */
  }
```

The [related documentation is here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_destroy.html).

Answer (score 1):

When running your code, I see the names printed in an unpredictable sequence, but I see no mangling like your output suggests. I'm using glibc 2.29-3 on Arch Linux.

Edit: I noticed that you are not calling `pthread_mutex_init`. Incidentally, the uninitialized (zero) `mt` appears to be lockable on my platform, but it may be causing the issue you are seeing on yours. I am not sure whether your platform is returning an error code when you call `pthread_mutex_lock` on account of it being uninitialized, but it would also be best to check the return value of those calls.